# rcc: File does not exist

Tags: qt, qmake, rcc

i am using a custom version of [QLed](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php?content=72482&forumpage=1) for my project. Actually it worked fine when i first included the files in my project. Somehow i end up with this weird error from rcc now. The .svg files are shown when executing the UI. This is my project's folder:

```
|-- _UI_Projects
|   |-- XmlReader
|   |   |-- include
|   |   |   |-- ...
|   |   |-- resources
|   |   |   |-- circle_black.svg
|   |   |   |-- circle_blue.svg
|   |   |   |-- circle_green.svg
|   |   |   |-- ...
|   |   |-- src
|   |   |   |-- ...
|   |   |-- qled.qrc
|   |   `-- xml_reader.pro
```

and `qmake-qt4 ~/_UI_Projects/XmlReader/xml_reader.pro` gives me:

`/usr/lib64/qt4/bin/rcc: File does not exist: '../_UI_Projects/XmlReader/qled.qrc`

This is my project file:

```
#####################################################
#                  My Project File                  #
#####################################################


greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += serialport

TEMPLATE = app

DEPENDPATH += . include resources src
INCLUDEPATH += . include

# Input
HEADERS += include/mainwindow.h \
            include/... (and so on)


SOURCES += src/main.cpp \
            src/...(and so on)

RESOURCES = qled.qrc

QT += svg
QT += testlib
```

I found few information on this rcc error so i would appreciate some help on this one.

**EDIT: Excerpt from qled.qrc added below**

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>resources/circle_green.svg</file>
        <file>resources/circle_grey.svg</file>
        <file>resources/circle_orange.svg</file>
        ... and so on and so on
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: Did you try to run a make clean? Maybe some error syntax in `qled.qrc`?

Comment: I did. `make` and `make clean` give no errors. I did not change `qled.qrc`. `qmake` also generates a Makefile but returns this error.

Comment: The error message suggests that the .qrc file isn’t found, so it’s not a problem with its content but its location. Somehow qmake might be confused regarding the path of the qrc file (paths relative to build directory vs. source directory etc.). I’d use `RESOURCES += $$PWD/qled.qrc` to see if it makes a difference and double-check for typos or case in the filename.

Comment: @Frank: tried as you suggested but still rcc says 'File does not exist'. Another weird fact might be that when i use qmake from qt5.5 under windows rcc works fine.